# How to bind the items count of listview in XAML

Tags: xaml, binding

I have a problem with binding the count to the textblock.

I have a listview that it's items are binded to a Users object properties.
I want to get the count of all items that were binded.

Here is my ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" x:Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <StackPanel>
                    <facebookControls:ProfilePicture Height="74" Width="74" ProfileId="{Binding FacebookId}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And here is my TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lvUsers, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know that if my ListView will be without Templates, just ListViewItems, it will work, but I need it to be like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the template for this `ListView`. 
The sample below basically creates a style where it overrides the control template such that the regular `ListView` items (the `ItemsPresenter`) is wrapped in the `StackPanel` so that the `TextBlock` with count or whatever else can be added at the bottom.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ScrollViewer>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,4" FontWeight="Bold">
                                        <Run Text="Count: "/>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                    
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewItem IsHitTestVisible="False">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <facebookControls:ProfilePicture Height="74" Width="74" ProfileId="{Binding FacebookId}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code is still not working. The problem is that the ListViewItems inside a ListView, how can I fix it?

Comment: The project is very big and I can't but the code is in my first statement at the top of the page...

Comment: if you are trying to put a listview inside another listview, what you need to do is override the template of the second one. Extract it, using blend, I bet (from experience using various DataGrids, my memory is failing me about ListView at the moment) inside the control template you will find a `Grid` there you can add additional rows, in that addional row put you `TextBlock` so it can be displayed as a part of that listview.

Comment: I have tried to do something like you said, but it's not working. Can you provide me some code please? Maybe I should remove the ListView.ItemTemplate, but then the question is, how can I bind the UserName and FacebookId? because without the template it returns me the ToString which is the name of the project...

Comment: you making me work, comrad!!! well, I have posted an update with the template, tested, this works... good luck!

Comment: Thanks, seems to work at wpf, but in windows store apps 8 - RelativeSource does not have a member AncestorType. How can I change it to do the same but without AncestorType?

Comment: oh, well, change it up as you had it where you named listview `<ListView x:Name="lv"`, then bind to element name, that WILL work `<Run Text="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>`